# Bit manipulation in C - builtin function

Tags: c, bitmask

Is there any builtin function in C that returns me the first bit equals to zero in a 32-bit integer?

I know I can check all 32-bit using a for-loop:

```
value <--- parameter (uint32_t)
for (int i=0; i<32; i++){
  uint32_t pos = 1 << i;
  if (pos ^ value) return i;  // xor
}
return -1;
```

Comment: By "First" do you mean the left most or right most bit?

Comment: right most. 31b__<<__0b

Comment: In gcc you can use: [__builtin_ctz](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)

Comment: There are no built-ins in C. Can you specify a compiler/platform?

Comment: You can use http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Leading%20Zero%20Count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no standardized C function to do this, but many C compilers offer one of their own.  When you use GCC it's the `_builtin_ctz` function.  When you use Microsoft Visual C it's the `_BitScanForward` function.

If you want to write programs that compile on multiple different compilers then you end up using a lot of `#ifdef` statements to provide the same thing in different ways.  (I keep hoping the C committee will mandate one of them already!)